# r data.frame pivoting and adding rows

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have a data.frame as below. It has many rows and multiple values in each column

```
ID=c(466,469,471,480,509,513,515,517,518,519,520,521,453,455,463,474,477,479,481,482,484,489,496,497,500,503)
name=c(rep("a",12),rep("b",14))
start=c(rep("2/13/2013",12),rep("3/6/2013",14))
end=c(rep("2/20/2013",12),rep("3/13/2013",14))
start=as.Date(start,"%m/%d/%Y")
end=as.Date(end,"%m/%d/%Y")

maint=data.frame(ID,name,start,end)

> (maint[1,])
   ID name      start        end
1 466    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
```

I would like to take the data and transform it as follows. I am providing example for the first row from the original data but I want same thing to be done to all the rows of the original data. Please advise how to do that.

I am taking start and end columns, then finding all the valid dates between them and creating a row for each date

```
ID  name    dates
466 a   2/13/2013
466 a   2/14/2013
466 a   2/15/2013
466 a   2/16/2013
466 a   2/17/2013
466 a   2/18/2013
466 a   2/19/2013
466 a   2/20/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a longer method in base R:

```
# get sequence of dates for each observation
mydates <- Map(function(x, y) seq(x, y, by="days"), as.Date(df$start), as.Date(df$end))
# get number of days for each observation
dates.length <- sapply(mydates, length)

# build a new data.frame
dfNew <- data.frame(ID=rep(df$ID, dates.length), 
                    name=rep(df$name, dates.length),
                    dates=as.Date(unlist(mydates), origin=as.Date("1970-01-01"))
```

As @user2100721 points out in the comments, the `Map` function may be simplified using `seq.Date` directly:

```
mydates <- Map(seq.Date, as.Date(df$start), as.Date(df$end), by="days")
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="ID name      start        end
1 466    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
2 467    b 2011-02-13 2011-02-22", as.is=T)
```

Comment: @user2100721 Got it. Thanks for the catch

Comment: You can use `seq.Date` inside of `Map` instead of defining a function.

Comment: I messed around with that for about 5 minutes before giving up and moving to an anonymous function.

Comment: Use this `as.Date(unlist(Map(seq.Date,as.Date(df$start),as.Date(df$end),by="days")),origin = as.Date("1970-01-01"))`

Comment: Aha, I was missing the final by argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(maint)`), grouped by 'ID', name' (assuming that there is only a single row for each combination), we get the `seq` of 'start' to 'end' .

```
library(data.table)
setDT(maint)[, .(dates = seq(start, end, by = "1 day")) , .(ID, name)]
```

Comment: I tried your method on the original csv file and i get the error `Error in is.finite(from) : 
  default method not implemented for type 'closure'`

Comment: @user2543622  I am not getting any error based on the example you provided